# Grouping by array elements and find sum of common array fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The document has an array field and each of them has a unique Id field. After doing unwind on the array, I need to add a count field on each array document instead of Id. The count should be the sum of similar array fields (grouped by fields other than Id).

Sample document - https://mongoplayground.net/p/LUPqVw07unP

Expected result:

```
{
    "originId": 123,
    "taskMetric": {
        "count": 2,
        "status": "OPEN",
        "assignee": "ABC"
    }
}, {
    "originId": 1,
    "taskMetric": {
        "count": 1,
        "status": "COMPLETED",
        "assignee": "CDE"
    }
}, {
    "originId": 1,
    "taskMetric": {
        "count": 1,
        "status": "COMPLETED",
        "assignee": "EFG"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4oZkLdqbOt0)

You have to add one more projection stage to avoid `_id` and add `id` to group stage as other fields to the following query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$tasks"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "status": "$tasks.status",
        "assignee": "$tasks.assignee"
      },
      "count": {
        $sum: 1
      },
      "status": {
        $first: "$tasks.status"
      },
      "assignee": {
        $first: "$tasks.assignee"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YX8AFpFwOst - this gave me the expected. Thanks @Gibbs